# script file referenced in PBK file fails to connect and crashes settings

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-desktop, ppp, ras

I have legacy code from Windows 95 that is still being worked on and sold.

It creates RAS dial-up entries that reference a script (*.scp) file in the DEVICE=switch section of the PBK file.  The entry is created using RASSetEntryPropertiesA() in C++. The script files is set using the RASENTRYA.szScript member.

This has worked up to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (W10A).  W10A shows the dialup entry, but attempting to edit it using the settings->network & internet->dial-up dialog actually crashes the dialog and the dialling fails with error 812 even though an attempt to dial has not occurred.  Editing the PBK file in notepad.exe and removing the DEVICE=switch section fixes the crash and dialling issue, but of course the connect fails because no connect script gets called.

Is this an actual bug in W10A or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in Windows 10.  Microsoft is "working on it"